# annotated hibernate mapping id/long foreign key to nullable column

Tags: java, hibernate, null, annotations, foreign-keys

I've got the following class mapping a MySQL table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private long parentId;
```

and I get the following error when dealing with columns that have NULL value of `parent_id` column:

`INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of com.blogspot.symfonyworld.wealthylaughingduck.model.Category.parentId`

This is just a java error: NULL can't be assigned to `long` type (`private long parentId`). I couldn't find any hint how to overcome this problem and I can only think of replacing `long` with `Long`. Is it a good idea or maybe there is some built-in hibernate annotation or whatever mechanism to do this particular stuff?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You defined your class attribute as a primitive (long), but your database table contains null values for the corresponding column. The provider (Hibernate) does not map null's to primitive because the mapping is ambiguous.

In cases where your data may contain nulls you need to use the wrapper class equivalent (in this case, Long).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Long parentId;
}
```

Comment: ok, so this is what I thought of. I just wondered if there's any additional annotation for that.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz - nope, no additional annotations needed. It's recommended (but not required) to annotate all primitive and wrapper type properties with `@Basic`.

Answer (score 1):

If `parentId` is nullable and you need to map it as a field, you'll need to use the wrapper class.

But if (as I suspect from the filed name) you're mapping foreign keys explicitly as fields, you're likely missing out on some of an ORM's real strength in [mapping associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association).